# how to convert an array of objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have the following array of object.

```
response: [0] 
          Data: '455'
          [1]
          Data: '456'
          [2]
          Data: '457'


var normalizedArray = newlist.map(function (obj) {
                    return obj.Data;
                });
```

I am able to convert the above array of Object into an array 'notmalizedArray' using the above function. this works and gives me following output.

```
normalizedArray= ['455', '456', '457'];
```

If instead of only 1 element, i have following array of objects.

```
response: [0] 
          Data: '455'
          Note: 'tre'
          Id: '4'
          [1]
          Data: '456'
          Note: 'bre'
          Id: '5'
          [2]
          Data: '457'
          Note: 'cre'
          Id: '6'
```

I want the following array output for the above array of objects.

```
normalizedArray = ['455', 'tre', '4', '456', 'bre', '5', '457', 'cre', '6']
```

Can someone let me know what should be changed in the below function to achive above shown normalizedArray.

```
var normalizedArray = newlist.map(function (obj) {
                return obj.Data;
            });
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to build up an array of arrays and then flatten them.

First, let's build the array, using `map` just as you did:

```
// ES6
let normalizedArr = response.map(function({Data, Note, Id}) {
    return [Data, Note, Id];
});
// before ES6
var normalizedArr = response.map(function(obj) {
    return [obj.Data, obj.Note, obj.Id];
});
```

Then we flatten it. There is no `flatten` Javascript function: we simply append each array in turn onto an empty array using [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
// ES6
let finalArr = [].concat(...normalizedArr);
// before ES6
var finalArr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], normalizedArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
var normalizedArray = newlist.map(function (obj) {
                return [obj.Data,obj.Note,obj.Id];
            });

var res = [];
normalizedArray .forEach(function(arr){res = res.concat(arr);})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using underscore's [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [**values**](http://underscorejs.org/#values) functions. The result of the map will be an array of arrays so [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) is then used to get one array:

```
var result = _.chain(response)
    .map(_.values)
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

With those code below, no matter the array objects have how many keys, the result will always be a flattened array.

```
// ES5
var normalizedArray = [];
response.forEach(function(obj) {
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(ele) {
      normalizedArray.push(obj[ele]);
   });
});
console.log(normalizedArray); // => ['455', 'tre', '4', '456', 'bre', '5', '457', 'cre', '6']

// ES6 one liner
let normalizedArray = [];
response.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(ele => normalizedArray.push(obj[ele])));

console.log(normalizedArray); // => ['455', 'tre', '4', '456', 'bre', '5', '457', 'cre', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var normalizedArray = newlist.reduce(function (resultArray, nextObj) {
                          resultArray.push(nextObj.Data, nextObj.Note, nextObj.Id);
                          return resultArray;
                      }, []);
```

`Array.prototype.reduce()` takes a reduction function and an initial value which is passed as the first parameter to that reduction function, the second argument is the next element in the array. Because we want to produce an array in the end, that's why there is a `[]` there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat to do it:

```js
var myArray = [
  {
   Data:  '455',
    Note: 'tre',
    Id: '4'
  }, {
    Data: '456',
    Note: 'bre',
    Id: '5'
  }, {
    Data: '457',
    Note: 'cre',
    Id: '6'
  }
];



var arr = myArray.map(function(obj)
 {
     return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });;
  });

var merged = [].concat.apply([], arr);

console.log(merged);
```